# isDisplayed returns false for a visible element in Protractor

Tags: javascript, html, css, protractor

**EDIT #4**: Breakthrough!!

I started recursively going through the parent nodes and returning the same values as below.  One of the parents--the inner `mat-drawer-container`--also returned false for isDisplayed (all the others returned true, which seems odd).

Looking at that node, it turns out that it's the only tag on the site to have the CSS of **`display: contents`**.  Removing that causes the button in question--*and* everything else below it--to return true for isDisplayed.  Heck, Protractor can even click the button and I can see the expected result in the browser.

Now I suppose the question remains: is this is expected behavior or a bug?  It's not as straightforward as there being an ancestor with display: contents applied; I applied it directly to `rb-container` and Protractor was still able to find the button.

---

I'm working on end-to-end testing in Protractor for the first time, and I'm running into an issue when trying to test for a button being visible; despite the button element being in the DOM and visible, isDisplayed returns false and my assertion fails.

This is the initial assertion that's been failing:

```
expect(element(by.css("mat-drawer-content rb-container rb-fab-button[data-qaid='create-button'] > button")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

(Yes, the selector is a mess, but I don't have control over the HTML.)

I've used a long browser.sleep() interval to essentially pause the browser in place so I could use the dev tools to inspect the humanly-visible element, and the CSS leads me to believe it should be detected as visible.

After searching for answers and/or bugs to no avail, I logged some information to the console which still leads me to believe that isDisplayed should return true:

[ ***EDITS #2, #3:** Logged some more information on all the direct children of rb-container; only one node is "visible", according to Protractor.* ]

```
  let selector = element.all(by.tagName("mat-drawer-content")).get(0).all(by.css("rb-container > *"));

  selector.count().then(function(selCount) {

    for (let match = 0; match < selCount; match ++) {

      browser.sleep(1000).then(() => {
        let elm = selector.get(match);

        console.log("\n >> " + match + "]");

        elm.getTagName().then(tag => { console.log("tag name:", tag); });
        elm.getCssValue("visibility").then(vis => { console.log("visibility:", vis); });
        elm.getCssValue("display").then(disp => { console.log("display:", disp); });
        elm.getCssValue("opacity").then(opa => { console.log("opacity:", opa); });
        elm.getCssValue("overflow").then(ov => { console.log("overflow:", ov); });
        elm.getAttribute("hidden").then(hid => { console.log("hidden:", hid); });
        elm.getAttribute("class").then(c => { console.log("class:", c)});
        elm.getSize().then(size => { console.log("size:", size); });
        elm.getCssValue("position").then(ov => { console.log("position:", ov); });
        elm.getLocation().then(loc => { console.log("location:", loc); });
        elm.isPresent().then(pres => { console.log("isPresent:", pres); });
        elm.isDisplayed().then(disp => { console.log("isDisplayed:", disp); });
      });

    }

  });
```

This is what I see logged:

```
 >> 0]
tag name: div
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: auto
hidden: null
class: title-tab dn db-m mediumGreyColor pl4 pv2 overflow-auto
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 62,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 898 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 0,
  y: 74.765625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 1]
tag name: div
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: auto
hidden: null
class: player-menu container overflow-auto dn db-m pv2 ng-star-inserted
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 64,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 834 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 32,
  y: 136.765625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 2]
tag name: rb-fab-button
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: visible
hidden: null
class: add-fab-button absolute dn db-m ng-star-inserted
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 56,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 56 }
position: absolute
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 762,
  y: 154.765625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 3]
tag name: div
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: visible
hidden: null
class: mr4-l w-100-m
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 0,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 834 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 32,
  y: 200.765625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 4]
tag name: rb-table-wrapper
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: visible
hidden: null
class: dn db-m
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 672,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 834 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 32,
  y: 200.765625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: true

 >> 5]
tag name: div
visibility: visible
display: block
opacity: 1
overflow: visible
hidden: null
class: container
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 0,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 834 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 32,
  y: 872.5625 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 6]
tag name: rb-table-wrapper
visibility: visible
display: none
opacity: 1
overflow: visible
hidden: null
class: db dn-m
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 0,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 0 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 0,
  y: 0 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false

 >> 7]
tag name: div
visibility: visible
display: none
opacity: 1
overflow: auto
hidden: null
class: player-menu container overflow-auto db dn-m ng-star-inserted
size: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 0,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 0 }
position: static
location: { ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  translate: {},
  x: 0,
  y: 0 }
isPresent: true
isDisplayed: false
```

With no hidden attribute set, a display value that isn't "none", visibility set to "visible", and non-zero size dimensions, I would expect isDisplayed to return true.

It's interesting to look at node 4, the only child element for which isDisplayed returns true, and compare it with node 2, the rb-fab-button element I'm trying to access.  The only noticeable difference I can see is that rb-fab-button is positioned absolutely; however, the other statically-positioned elements also return false for isDisplayed.

Am I missing something?  I'd settle for checking for css visibility, but my next test is to click that button, which errors if the element is not visible.

[ ***EDIT #1:** Added some HTML:* ]

```html
<mat-drawer-container _ngcontent-c0="" class="root-container w-100 mat-drawer-container mat-drawer-container-explicit-backdrop" hasbackdrop="true" ng-reflect-has-backdrop="true">
    <div class="mat-drawer-backdrop ng-star-inserted"></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
    <mat-drawer _ngcontent-c0="" class="mobile-drawer dn-m w-80 mat-drawer ng-tns-c2-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transform mat-drawer-over ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-mode="over" style="box-shadow: none; visibility: hidden;">
      <!-- [... mobile nav ...] -->
    </mat-drawer>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
    <mat-drawer-content _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-drawer-content">
        <rb-navbar _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <!-- [... nav bar ...] -->
        </rb-navbar>
        <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="main-body">
            <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="container h-100">
                <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
                <rb-system-setup _nghost-c18="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                    <router-outlet _ngcontent-c18=""></router-outlet>
                    <rb-site-tab class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <mat-drawer-container autosize="" class="mat-drawer-container" ng-reflect-autosize="">
                            <div class="mat-drawer-backdrop ng-star-inserted"></div>
                            <div tabindex="-1" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
                            <mat-drawer class="mat-drawer ng-tns-c2-8 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transform mat-drawer-end mat-drawer-over ng-star-inserted" disableclose="true" mode="over" position="end" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-position="end" ng-reflect-mode="over" ng-reflect-disable-close="true" style="box-shadow: none; visibility: hidden;">
                                <rb-create-site _nghost-c20="" ng-reflect-side-panel="[object Object]" ng-reflect-side-panel-container="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-grid="[object Object]" ng-reflect-is-editing="false" ng-reflect-timezones="[object Object],[object Object">
                                    <rb-side-panel _ngcontent-c20="" _nghost-c24="" ng-reflect-title="Add Site" ng-reflect-close-button-label="Cancel" ng-reflect-submit-button-label="CREATE_SITE.SUBMIT" ng-reflect-show-submit-button="true" ng-reflect-modal-submitting="true" ng-reflect-side-panel-container="[object Object]">
                                      <!-- [... side panel ...] -->
                                    </rb-side-panel>
                                </rb-create-site>
                            </mat-drawer>
                            <div tabindex="-1" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
                            <mat-drawer-content cdkscrollable="" class="mat-drawer-content ng-star-inserted">
                                <div class="ph4-m h-100">
                                    <rb-card _nghost-c21="">
                                        <div _ngcontent-c21="" class="card rb-min-width-1 h-100">
                                            <div _ngcontent-c21="" class="relative h-100">
                                                <rb-container _nghost-c22="" ng-reflect-row-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-show-player="true" ng-reflect-show-search-bar="true" ng-reflect-include-edit="true" ng-reflect-include-delete="true" ng-reflect-include-stop="false" ng-reflect-include-sync="false" ng-reflect-include-checkbox="true" ng-reflect-include-fab-button="true" ng-reflect-route-type="systemSetup" ng-reflect-header="Sites" ng-reflect-mobile-table="site" ng-reflect-show-site-selector="false" ng-reflect-mobile-navigation="true">
                                                    <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="title-tab dn db-m mediumGreyColor pl4 pv2 overflow-auto">
                                                        <h1 _ngcontent-c22="" class="header-text pa2 fl ng-star-inserted">Sites</h1></div>
                                                    <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="player-menu container overflow-auto dn db-m pv2 ng-star-inserted">
                                                      <!-- [... player menu ...] -->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <rb-fab-button _ngcontent-c22="" class="add-fab-button absolute dn db-m ng-star-inserted" data-qaid="create-button" _nghost-c28="">
                                                        <button _ngcontent-c28="" class="w-10 z-1 mat-fab mat-accent" mat-fab="" type="button" ng-reflect-disabled="false"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><mat-icon _ngcontent-c28="" aria-label="add" class="mat-icon material-icons ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">add</mat-icon></span>
                                                            <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div>
                                                            <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </rb-fab-button>
                                                    <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="mr4-l w-100-m"></div>
                                                    <rb-table-wrapper _ngcontent-c22="" class="dn db-m" ng-reflect-row-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-enable-sorting="true" ng-reflect-include-checkbox="true" ng-reflect-is-clickable="false" ng-reflect-row-selection="multiple" ng-reflect-dom-layout="" ng-reflect-columns="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-un-select-all_="[object Object]" ng-reflect-mobile-table="site" ng-reflect-mobile-navigation="true" ng-reflect-row-drag="false" ng-reflect-row-drag-field-name="">
                                                        <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material" ng-reflect-grid-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-row-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-column-defs="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-default-col-def="[object Object]" ng-reflect-row-selection="multiple" ng-reflect-suppress-row-click-selection="true" ng-reflect-enable-sorting="true" ng-reflect-enable-filter="true" ng-reflect-suppress-no-rows-overlay="true" ng-reflect-dom-layout="" ng-reflect-row-drag-managed="false">
                                                          <!-- [... data grid ...] -->
                                                        </ag-grid-angular>
                                                        <div class="backgroundColor w-100 fixed bottom-0 left-0 dn db-m ng-star-inserted">
                                                            <div class="item-selection fr w-20">0/ 1 Selected</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </rb-table-wrapper>
                                                    <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="player-menu container overflow-auto db dn-m ng-star-inserted"></div>
                                                </rb-container>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </rb-card>
                                </div>
                            </mat-drawer-content>
                        </mat-drawer-container>
                    </rb-site-tab>
                </rb-system-setup>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="snacks fixed mw6 rb-min-width-2">
                <rb-global-snack-bar _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-3">
                    <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="snackBar">
                        <ul _ngcontent-c8="" class="ma0 pa0 list"></ul>
                    </div>
                </rb-global-snack-bar>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: Is it possible to post some of the HTML for that element? Also, it may be possible to do a pseudo check with `browser.wait(ExpectedCondition.visibilityOf())`

Comment: Sleep more time, like `browser.sleep(15*1000) // 15 secs`. And check the button's any ancestors is invisible.

Comment: 1. I think isPresent is more reliable in your case to verify and make assert pass
expect($('.item').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
also increase browser.sleep wait to verify isDisplayed() output

Comment: I agree that the result is somewhat unexpected. You might try this code to get some insight.
`var elm = element(by.xpath("..."));  
var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  
browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(elm), 5000);
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);`

Comment: @BenMohorc: Same conundrum there: presenceOf will let it pass, but visibilityOf simply times out, no matter how much time I allow.

Comment: @yong: I've used 60 seconds to let myself manually inspect the DOM, but it still never found it to be visible.  (Right now, the sleep I listed is just for troubleshooting purposes so that the whole list is executed together.)

Comment: @Amit: Unfortunately, while isPresent will tell me that it exists in the DOM, my next test is to use click() to test that clicking the button does what is expected; if Protractor doesn't believe that the button is visible, it errors.

Comment: @yong: As for the ancestors, isVisible returns true for "mat-drawer-content rb-container", but false for "mat-drawer-content rb-container rb-fab-button", which returns the same values for visibility, etc, as I posted above.

Comment: @Bouke: Unfortunately, using the xpath didn't change anything:  //mat-drawer-content//rb-container worked with visibilityOf, but //mat-drawer-content//rb-container//rb-fab-button timed out.  Using the latter xpath with presenceOf moved past the wait, but failed on the expect statement.

Comment: @kj.
Can you try expected condition class ---
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

Comment: Did the `browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(elm), 5000)` time out?

Comment: @Amit I've tried that, and I've had the same results with presenceOf vs visibilityOf.

Comment: @Bouke with the larger xpath, yes.  presenceOf works and moves on, but visibilityOf times out.

Comment: @BenMohorc: I've added an HTML snippet.

Comment: At least the failure is consistent then...

Comment: @kj, Because its parent: '<rb-fab-button' isDispalyed() return false, so any child of `<rb-fab-button` will be treated invisible. Your key work now is to investigate which attribute/style class make selenium think `<rb-fab-button` is not display.

Comment: @yong: That makes sense, of course, but that leaves the question of why it's coming up as not visible when it's present in the DOM, has size, and has visibility.

Comment: I added some new logging information, but none of it is really helping me figure out why this is happening.  I went through the criteria in [the Selenium source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js), and don't see where it might be failing.

Comment: This is the definition of displayness on Webdriver specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness.  To figure out the reason, I think you need a CSS master.

Comment: If an element's parent is not visible then the element is invisible. This is sensible, logical and well defined behavior in CSS specs.

Comment: @SalmanA: You're right, of course.  So rather than focusing on the button element, I'm switched focus to why its parent, rb-fab-button, isn't visible. I feel like, according to what I'm seeing in the console log I posted, it should be, but it seems that Protractor disagrees.

Comment: @kj can you actually see the button?

Comment: @SalmanA With my eyes?  Yes.

Comment: It would be nice to have a github project with a simple angular app that you can reproduce this error along with your protractor config and protractor script. I'll help come up with a solution

Comment: I had a bit of a breakthrough!  See my latest edit.

Comment: @kj post your breakthrough as an answer. It might be as good as it gets, that way it is easily accessible if someone else has this issue

Comment: @kj i did not read your post enough but this looks like a glitch. I believe `display: contents` should be considered visible (it simply means that assume the element is not there and its children replace the element). Since it is a new property and perhaps the code that determines if an element or its parent is visible does not handle this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started recursively going through the parent nodes and returning the same values as below.  One of the parents--the inner `mat-drawer-container`--also returned false for isDisplayed (all the others returned true, which seems odd).

Looking at that node, it turns out that it's the only tag on the site to have the CSS of **`display: contents`**.  Removing that causes the button in question--*and* everything else below it--to return true for isDisplayed.  Heck, Protractor can even click the button and I can see the expected result in the browser.

Now I suppose the question remains: is this is expected behavior or a bug?  It's not as straightforward as there being an ancestor with display: contents applied; I applied it directly to `rb-container` and Protractor was still able to find the button.

I opened [an issue on the protractor GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4951) so they could look further into it.

---

[**UPDATE:** I've updated the issue on GitHub, but thought I'd share here as well:]

After some digging, I've found that it's a combination of two style declarations: `display: contents` with `overflow: hidden`.

On the surface, it sounds like common sense that you shouldn't really use those together, since you're trying to hide the overflow of a container element that isn't really there; however, I feel if a child of said element is being rendered visibly by the browser--and in this case, it is--it probably should be detected as visible by protractor.

The HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>isDisplayed() issue</title>
    <style>

    .not-displayed .display-contents {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: contents; 
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="not-displayed">
    <div class="display-contents">
        <div class="wrong">isDisplayed() returns false</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="displayed">
    <div class="display-contents">
        <div class="right">isDisplayed() returns true</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Spec file:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('Testing the Protractor Bug', () => {

    it('should display debugging info', () => {

        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get('_[file location]_');

        element(by.css('.wrong')).isDisplayed().then(disp => { console.log('"wrong" isDisplayed:', disp); });
        element(by.css('.right')).isDisplayed().then(disp => { console.log('"right" isDisplayed:', disp); });

    });
});
```

The output from that:

```
[17:04:50] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:04:50] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59412/devtools/browser/3f76f1a9-25f5-4497-8ae3-6933d01d0c7e
Jasmine started
"wrong" isDisplayed: false
"right" isDisplayed: true

  Testing the Protractor Bug
    √ should display debugging info

Executed 1 of 1 spec SUCCESS in 0.202 sec.
[17:04:53] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[17:04:53] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Comment: Agreed. May I add that apparently the function considers 0-sized elements (width = 0, height = 0) as invisible unless the element has a non-0-size child, in which case it also checks if the 0-size element for `overflow: hidden`. This is correct but then `display: contents` (a recently added feature) changes it. It roughly means that the element itself is replaced by its children so the properties such as border, padding, background and (perhaps) overflow should be ignored.