# Protractor/Cucumber/Selenium Running test it fails cause it can't find an element that is present on the page

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumber

I'm using Protractor (with Javascript) to run my automatic tests.
Sometimes happen that a test fails cause it can't find an element that is present on the page.

My Html:

```
<div class="card-date">05 Dec</div>
```

My Steps definitions:

```
Then('I see a card-date', {timeout: 50*1000} , function (next) {
    var card_date = element(by.css('.card-date'));
    expect(card_date.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(next);
});
```

My Attempt with browser.wait in the step definition:

```
    Then('I see a card-date', {timeout: 50*1000} , function (next) {
      var card_date = element(by.css('.card-date'));
      var expected = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      browser.wait(expected.visibilityOf(card_date));
      expect(card_date.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(next);
      next();
    });
```

I tried with this too:

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return card_date.isDisplayed().then(function(IsVisible) {
            return IsVisible;
        });
    }, 10000);
    expect(card_date.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(next);
```

Error:

```
AssertionError
       + expected - actual

       -false
       +true
```

I tried to recover the text of the element by managing promise, so i could have the length of the string of the element and checks if it is a number above 0. If this condition is true, the element is obviously present. But when I launch the test, it can't read inside my promise. The console log is never shown on my console.

Why this is happen if the element is present on the page??
At the moment of the fail I can see the browser opened normally in the right page and the element is always present.

Comment: Are there iframes present on the page? Also are you able to find element when you search for it in dev tools?

Comment: Did you try with wait for the date field?

Comment: @BenMohorc Yes, I can.

Comment: @Navarasu Yes. I edited the question with my attempt

Comment: So you are not getting timeout error for wait? Still assertion is getting failed?

Comment: @Navarasu Yes. The assertion is still getting failed

Comment: This sounds a little bit like this question I ran into awhile back. Might have some useful info, but it was never truly solved so...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174578/isdisplayed-returns-false-for-a-visible-element-in-protractor

Comment: @BenMohorc What can i do? I can't test old stuffs for my customer. Is there a way around the problem

Comment: @Spicchio on the question I linked, in edit #2 and #3 the OP runs code to get all the values of the element he is trying to click. Could you do something similar? Its possible there is some weird css thing that you arent realizing

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you @BenMohorc it helped me to solve the issue